# Page title replaced in IE if fragment identifier set

Tags: html, apache-flex, internet-explorer

In IE, with Flex application embedded, changing page location with JS like that:

```
document.location.href = "#someFragmentIdentifier";
```

causes change of page title to "#someFragmentIdentifier". I've read that the cause of that was supposed to be integration of Flex application with browser navigation, so I disabled it at the Flex compiler properties screen, however it didn't fix anything. Could anybody help me by pointing some working solution to this unwanted behavior.

Thanks.

PS: You can easily reproduce that by starting your Flex application and changing current URL by hand so it contains fragment identifier and then refreshing the page.

Comment: I have the same problem without any flex, just plain IE and javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've run into this using various ajax toolkits, including MS's.

It is not limited to Flex, flash, or any Adobe tech.  It is purely a browser issue.

Unfortunately, the *ONLY* workaround we've found that was worthwhile involved "changing the title with javascript".

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It is the only work-around that actually works.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in Adobe's bug tracker with various workarounds. I guess one of them should work...
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-240

Comment: All of them are variations of "Change the title with javascript", which is fine but we change the page with ajax and would like a general solution without adding "document.title = 'blah'" to the end of every ajax callback.  Thanks a lot for the link, though, now I am pretty sure it is flash-related!

Comment: Please all of us : register on adobe and vote for this issue !

Comment: This URL no longer works. Apparently the bug database is being transitioned to the Apache project.

Comment: A snapshot of the page (from 2009) is available at [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20090222065006/http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-240). The bug itself is available in Adobe's new bugbase as [Bug #2927932](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2927932). However, the comments from the old bug didn't get moved over.